# Single TextBox style to show negative numbers in red for all of them

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatrigger

At the first glance the task looks similar to
[WPF TextBlock Negative Number In Red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205096/wpf-textblock-negative-number-in-red)

In my case I have to display in an `ItemsControl` a collection of Points. Each Point has several properties of type NumericValue that is ultimately a wrapper around `Nullable<double>`.

```
public class Point
{
    NumericValue Proposal { get; set; }
    NumericValue Accepted { get; set; }
    NumericValue Approved { get; set; }
    ... etc.
}
```

I display all those properties of a Point as TextBoxes. The class NumericValue has the property IsNegative and I want the Foreground of the corresponding Textbox to be red if IsNegative=True.

However, I'd prefer not to define this rule in a style for each individual TextBox but to make a **single** style with DataTrigger bound to IsNegative.

The simplified XAML looks like the one below.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Points}">
...
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.Proposal.Value}" ... />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.Accepted.Value}" ... />
...
</ItemsControl>
```

Please help me with the binding definition for the DataTrigger of that single style.

Comment: > Please help me with the binding definition for the DataTrigger of that single style. Binding="{Binding IsNegative}"

Comment: Does not seem to work. I tried this with the original textbox binding, and then tried also <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.Proposal}" ... /> that seems more logical to me in regards to {Binding IsNegative}. In any case the IsNegative property was not  even called.

Comment: The unconditional setters of the style work fine.

Comment: If the DataContext is not the point itself, which you seem to indicate here you need to modify the binding, if that `Data` property is the point the binding would be `{Binding Data.IsNegative}` (which here is equivalent to `{Binding Path=Data.IsNegative}`). If a binding does not do anything you should try to [debug it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the converter given at [WPF TextBlock Negative number in red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205096/wpf-textblock-negative-number-in-red) like this

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Points}">
        ...
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Data.Proposal.Value}" Foreground="{Binding Data.Proposal.IsNegative, Converter={StaticResource valueToBackground}}" />
        ...
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd prefer to keep all the coloring stuff within XAML, so I'll use this method only as the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow [How to: Conditional formatting using XAML in WPF](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2011/04/how-to-conditional-xaml-in-wpf.html). I think it will be helpful for you.